# Speeding up my VBA code

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a code which is doing some calculations in 8 columns and several hundred rows. The  code currently works but takes a while to run. I'd like to speed up my code. I have heard about using variant arrays as they speed up the macro. Currently I have managed to use the arrays to read data and store it in an array before outputting it to a separate worksheet. Variables not declared in the code below are public.

```
Sub BBHCashRecon()
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .DisplayStatusBar = False
                .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                .EnableEvents = False
            End With


'Worksheets
     Set BBHNAV = Worksheets("BBH NAV")

   With BBHNAV
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
'For each row in the 'BBH NAV' sheet with data...
    For n = 2 To LastRow
        'Unique Identifier
        .Range("A" & n).Value = .Range("J" & n).Value & .Range("M" & n).Value
    Next n

    For n = 2 To LastRow

        'Base Market Value
            .Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('T-1 DATA'!G:G,MATCH(1,('T-1 DATA'!A:A='BBH NAV'!A2)*('T-1 DATA'!D:D='BBH NAV'!L2),0),1)," & """NO DATA""" & ")"
            .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).FillDown
        'calculate columns B otherwise column C for some reason is using the value in B2 which is filldown when running the calculation
        .Range("B" & n).Calculate

        '% change in NAV
        If .Range("B" & n).Value = "NO DATA" Then
            .Range("C" & n).Value = "NO DATA"
        Else
            .Range("C" & n).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError((.Range("O" & n).Value / .Range("B" & n).Value) - 1, "ERROR")
        End If

        'change in NAV
        If .Range("B" & n).Value = "NO DATA" Then
            .Range("D" & n).Value = "NO DATA"
        Else
            .Range("D" & n).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(.Range("O" & n).Value - .Range("B" & n).Value, "ERROR")
        End If

        'Market Value
        .Range("E" & n).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("J:J"), .Range("J" & n).Value, .Range("O:O"))

        'Column F and G
            'ID for assets
                ID = Left(.Range("L" & n).Value, 4)
                If ID = "CASH" Then
                    .Range("F" & n).Value = 1
                Else
                    .Range("F" & n).Value = 0
                End If

        'BBH# & column F
        .Range("G" & n).Value = .Range("J" & n).Value & .Range("F" & n).Value

        'Cash Balance
        .Range("H" & n).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("G:G"), .Range("G" & n).Value, .Range("O:O")) * .Range("F" & n).Value

    Next n

       'conditional formatting for column c of values not between plus or minus 3%
            With .Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
                .Style = "Percent": .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, Formula1:="=-0.03", Formula2:="=0.03": .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            End With
            With .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic: .Color = 14481404
            End With
            .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
 End With
      With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = True
       .DisplayStatusBar = True
       .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
       .EnableEvents = True
   End With
   End Sub
```

Comment: You should read up on Dictionaries and Class Modules. They are the best way to go here if you want good performance.

Comment: @jmdon - how specifically would using a class module improve performance here?

Comment: It's well documented that reading data stored in Ranges is less efficient than reading data stored in Class Modules / Arrays.

Comment: @jmdon thanks for the feedback. Still fairly new to vba so not fulling understanding your suggestion. Will read up on dictionaries but in the meantime is there anything obvious I can do? this is part of a spreadsheet I need to present soon.

Comment: Is your spreadsheet just the data or do you need to have the results in the sheet?  Is it always the same sheet or will it differ?  Maybe you could use another scripting language such as php and save the xls file as a csv read it and do calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started:

Excel is smart enough to increment row references.

This:

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
'For each row in the 'BBH NAV' sheet with data...
    For n = 2 To LastRow
        'Unique Identifier
        .Range("A" & n).Value = .Range("J" & n).Value & .Range("M" & n).Value
    Next n
```

Can be written like this and completely avoids a loop:

```
Range("N2:N" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=J2 & M2"
Range("N2:N" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).copy
Range("N2:N" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).pastespecial xlPasteValues
application.CutCopyMode = false
```

It inserts the formula, copies it, pastes as values over itself then sets the cutcopymode to false, you don't really need this last line if you are going to copy and paste something else as the next copy kills this copy reference.

Have a go at trying to replace your current loops to use this method and post back if you get stuck. Your if statements can also be converted to a simple if formula that would be used in a sheet then done with the same method I have posted.